# apache tomcat to redirect to new url

Tags: jsp, tomcat, redirect

Currently, I am hosting a webapp at http://sample1.com:8080/UI_V2/. I am using apache tomcat for hosting it. Now, I want to get rid of this sample1 box. But for a few days, I want to redirect all the requests which comes to http://sample1.com:8080/UI_V2/ **to the new box** **http://sample2.com:8080/UI_V2/**

How do I do that?

Comment: try this may it solve you issue, it work in my case http://serverfault.com/questions/602275/redirect-url-to-a-tomcat-webapp

Answer (score 2):

Put an Apache httpd in front of it and set up a `ProxyPass` to point to sample2. This way you'll be able to switch things easier.